# Does disabling VT-d and interrupt remapping break MSI-X?

Tags: debian, dell-poweredge, intel, broadcom, interrupts

So I have a `Dell PowerEdge R610` server running `Debian Jessie` which according to some docs has a faulty chipset: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7014344 (`Intel 5500 rev 13`).

The provided shell test confirms the presence of this chipset: `lspci -nn | grep -qE '8086:(340[36].*rev 13|3405.*rev (12|13|22))' && echo "Interrupt remapping is broken"`

It has `VT-d` disabled in BIOS and has `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intremap=off"` added to the `/etc/grub/default`.

My question is, does this affect the `MSI-X` feature of NIC cards (Which should spread interrupts among cores)?

On this particular server indeed only one core is servicing interrupts, but I am not sure if this is the result of the disabled BIOS and kernel settings. Or something else could be at play?

(Unfortunately I have no access to the BIOS to change settings and test things with the features turned on).

Thank you.

```
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7
   0:         43          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
   1:          3          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
   8:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
   9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
  12:          4          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  16:      15459          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   megasas
  17:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3
  18:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4
  19:         28          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
  20:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb6
  21:        398          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2, uhci_hcd:usb5
  23:      50805          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ata_piix
  72:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME
  73:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME
  74:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME
  75:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME
  76:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME
  95:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  96:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  97:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  98:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
  99:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
 100:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
 101:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
 102:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ioat-msix
 103:  126464280          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-0
 104:   92145436          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-1
 105:   89096948          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-2
 106:   88057555          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-3
 107:   81812555          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-4
 108:   89599897          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-5
 109:   88031686          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-6
 110:   87201395          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth2-7
 112:  377125739          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-0
 113:      72913          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-1
 114:    1890421          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-2
 115:  162242342          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-3
 116:      53494          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-4
 117:      85112          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-5
 118:      44281          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-6
 119:      41480          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-7
 NMI:      39120        194        382        197        337        184        276        186   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:  217815785    1972192    4721954    2056033    2252897    1834404    1894099    1739779   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:      39120        194        382        197        337        184        276        186   Performance monitoring interrupts
 IWI:          8          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
 RTR:          7          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
 RES:     133678      35960      21042       9616      10918       8463       8607       8143   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:       1815       3264       1626       3885       1970       3807       1972       4000   Function call interrupts
 TLB:        896        110        258        139        200        110        187         81   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:        171        171        171        171        171        171        171        171   Machine check polls
 HYP:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Hypervisor callback interrupts
 ERR:          0
 MIS:          0
```

The NIC settings:

```
root@server:~# lspci -v

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
        Memory at d6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=9 Masked-
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 84-2b-2b-ff-fe-fe-b3-bd
        Capabilities: [110] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2

01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
        Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=9 Masked-
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 84-2b-2b-ff-fe-fe-b3-bf
        Capabilities: [110] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
        Memory at da000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=9 Masked-
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 84-2b-2b-ff-fe-fe-b3-c1
        Capabilities: [110] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2

02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R610 BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
        Memory at dc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=9 Masked-
        Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 84-2b-2b-ff-fe-fe-b3-c3
        Capabilities: [110] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2


root@server:~# ethtool -k eth0

Features for eth0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
        tx-checksum-ipv4: on
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-ipv6: on
        tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
        tx-tcp-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: off
udp-fragmentation-offload: off [fixed]
generic-segmentation-offload: off
generic-receive-offload: off
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: off [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipip-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sit-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-mpls-segmentation: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off [fixed]
rx-all: off [fixed]
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
busy-poll: off [fixed]


root@server:~# ethtool -i eth0
driver: bnx2
version: 2.2.5
firmware-version: 7.12.17 bc 7.10.0 NCSI 2.0.13
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. MSI-X needs interrupt remapping enabled to fully work.

From a Intel PDF:
[Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-specifications/vt-directed-io-spec.pdf)
Architecture Specification
October 2014

> **5.1 Interrupt Remapping**
>
> The interrupt-remapping architecture enables system software to control and censor external interrupt requests generated by all sources including those from interrupt controllers (I/OxAPICs), MSI/MSI-X capable devices including endpoints, root-ports and Root-Complex integrated end-points.

Comment: Bummer :(. Thanks. I wonder If I could manually assign  IRQS/NICs to each CPU. This would be better than nothing, and is pretty crucial since this server mainly does routing and the remaining CPUs stay idle.

Comment: So your /proc/interrupts output indicates that the NIC queues are being assigned to separate interrupts by MSI-X but not distributed across cores. In Linux interrupt mapping across cores for pluggable devices is usually performed in userland via irqbalance. Does running this correctly balance your system?

Comment: No, I haven't enabled/installed irqbalance. I will in this case and see if it makes a difference. Although if according to the above intel docs VT-d and/or the intremapping=off kernel parameters control this feature then I guess this won't help. : (

Comment: @TerryBurton So I ran irqbalance and now I am seeing some interrupts on all the CPUs for the NIC queues. However I also had a crash of my NIC card, can't tell if it was irqbalance's fault, because the timestamp is a bit earlier: http://pastebin.com/pfu8vYPd

Comment: Will not be irqbalance's fault directly but if the BIOS is buggy like your report suggests you may find hardware interrupts mapped to non-existant CPU lines, stalling your TX/RX queues. This is different from mapping IRQs to cores. Does the NIC recover from this state when you trigger a self-test using ethtool?

Comment: @TerryBurton Yes, it seems it recovered automatically. According to dmesg output it was down for about 2 seconds. The switch on the other end reported the same down/up event.

Comment: @krdx The original problem can be fixed with a firmware upgrade. Of course, this means you have to gain access to your BIOS...

Comment: So I recall having to disable MSI/MSI-X on certain BNX + Intel board combinations. Not ideal since you lose all of the benefit of a multi-queue NIC but it should see you through until you update firmware and afterwards if the problem persists. Module option described here: http://karellen.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/disable-msi-on-bnx2-driver.html?m=1

Comment: @TerryBurton Thanks for the link. I actually think this particular R610 is up to date, or at least it was updated via Dell UCS a month or so ago. Can't check until my colleague gets back from holidays. Anyway I think you are on point with the MSI feature causing trouble, for example I have an identical Dell R610, running on FreeBsd instead of Debian, It has two nics, one intel (ixgbe) , the second the same broadcom (bce) and when I check the the irq handlers it shows none for broadcom: http://pastebin.com/NvZqg1B8 (so it seems freebsd disabled it automatically since I never touched it)